# how to efficiently build a rippled roof?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I'm currently trying to reproduce this in Blender:

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the roof and it's "ripples". I haven't found a proper texture yet and testing with other metal textures doesn't give me the feeling I wanted.

Making many loop cuts might give me a feel but it's also very performance-consuming. Another option could be using a wave texture but I wonder if this is the best solution. What do you guys think?

Comment: Hi, Christian. I edited your question and put the picture directly into it so it follows the guidelines of the platform a bit better. Hopefully it will make it easier for the people who might attempt to answer. Hope you don't mind. Also, the picture does not show the roof very clearly. It's a bit hard to see how it is made so this might be an obstacle for solving the problem. Do you maybe have some more image of what exactly you are after? If not it's definitely a good idea to find some.

Comment: Hello Martynas, thanks for your comment. I purposely didn't upload the picture as it wasn't mine and I wasn't sure about copyright. What I'd like to achieve is to have an iron roof that comes close to look like that: [Link](https://www.stratco.com.au/globalassets/catalog/gallery/cladding-roofing-sheeting-walling-corrugated-maximus-08.jpg)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: now you are just one step away from prison... :D

Comment: You could use an Array modifier to repeat the same pattern, have you tried? If it's not for close-up shots you could also bake the normals

Answer (score 0):

You can loop cut a plane several times, select every other edge and move up on the Z axis.

[image]

Then *Shade Smooth* and select all the short edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> *Bevel* to the desired depth.

[image]

[image]

Or just apply a *Wave Texture* as Bump data for the texture (mind the *Distance* value).

[image]